# Macbook Pro 2011 A1278 Keyboard Diagnosis

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware

A MBP keyboard is unreliable to the point where a USB keyboard is a workaround.

Googled the issue presents many software based remedies.

What tests can be performed to confirm that that the problem is hardware? or software?

Is this a known defect with this particular model?

Comment: Isn't " a USB keyboard is a workaround." proof enough that it is not so much a software issue?

Comment: The test for eliminating software issues is to try an external keyboard.  If it works ok, the internal one can usually be presumed damaged.

Answer (score 1):

You are lucky to have a keyboard that lasted 7 Years.

Normally their life span is much less, and it depends on your eating habits (yes, eating, believe it or not).

Best way to keep it clean and last longer in the future

1. use compressed air can from time to time
2. buy a ~$6 transparent cover foil made to fit your model keyboard
3. replacing individual keys is possible if you are a surgeon
4. no comment on eating habits

As for hardware test, use the builtin Apple Hardware test. That might show a problem or not.

Hold D key during restart and follow the instructions.

Comment: Replacing keycaps is very easy, individual keys is impossible, as you need a full keyboard-board to do this. Well, in later MBPs it is even ever more complicated in how the topcase is constructed.